# C++ operator() overload boost::system::error_code trick

Tags: c++, boost

I've seen a nice trick made by an boost Implementation, they somehow use the overloading of the () operator to evaluate an instance of the class boost::system::error_code to an bool value

```
class error_code
{
...
typedef void (*unspecified_bool_type)();
static void unspecified_bool_true() {}

operator unspecified_bool_type() const  // true if error
{ 
  return m_val == 0 ? 0 : unspecified_bool_true;
}
...
}
```

This results in the possibility to check for an error like this

```
...
boost::system::error_code err

some_boost_func(err);
if(err)
{
    //handle error
}
....
```

So i keep asking myself.. what happend there?
This seems to somehow relate to the use of function pointers...
What happens if i call `err` does this evaluate the function itself or the function pointer?
But how can a `void (*unspecified_bool_type)();` function return a value in

```
return m_val == 0 ? 0 : unspecified_bool_true;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It really has little (or nothing) to do with core functionality of *function* pointers specifically. It is a trick that allows one to write a "safe" boolean-like conversion for the class.

When one wants some class to be usable under `if` (and generally in logic contexts), one typically makes it convertible to `bool`. As in

```
class Error {
public:
  operator bool() const { /* whatever */ }
};
```

and now you can do

```
Error err;
...
if (err) // automatically intepreted as `if (err.operator bool())`
  ...
```

However, since `bool` type is an integral type in C++, this might lead to undesirable consequences, when someone accidentally writes something like

```
int i = err;
```

or uses `err` in an arithmetic expression and it quietly compiles.

For this reason, in many cases people prefer to introduce a conversion to *pointer* type, instead of conversion to `bool`, as in

```
class Error {
public:
  operator void *() const { 
    // Return null pointer for `false` and any non-null pointer for `true`
  }
};
```

This is better since one can use it under `if`, but one can't make the previous mistake with `int`. I.e.

```
 if (err) // automatically interpreted as `if (err.operator void *() != 0)`
   ...
```

will compile and work as intended, since the compiler will automatically convert `err` object to pointer type.

However, such conversion will be automatically applied in pointer contexts as well (in addition to boolean contexts), meaning that one can still accidentally do

```
void *p = err;
```

or

```
free(err);
```

and it will quietly compile. This is also undesirable.

To make it more difficult to accidentally misuse such error class, it is a good idea to use some more "exotic" pointer type, like pointer to a function. This is exactly what you see in the code you quoted. The `unspecified_bool_type` is used as a pointer-based pseudo-boolean type. Null value is returned for `false` and pointer to a dummy `unspecified_bool_true` function is returned for `true`. The function `unspecified_bool_true` is never called and never intended to be called. It only exists to reserve some unique pointer value to be used as `true` return.

In some cases people take it one step further and use an even more "exotic" pointer type:  pointer-to-class-member type. But for most applications pointer to function is "exotic" enough.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and precise answer. So this was a conversion and has nothing to do with functions